# Script for getting the content from a webpage or HTML file

Tags: html

By "getting the content from a webpage" I mean something like what Pocket does i.e. it strips the page from all extraneous links, social media buttons, ads and other embellishments. The webpages in questions are mostly articles. A script in any programming language would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make with PHP + cURL relatively easy. You must to investigate PHP language and cURL extension. You get HTML like a DOM that you can manipulate, and parse the HTML removing all you don't want to show.

When you have a problem with your script come with us to resolve as soon as possible.

Good luck.